# Return value by pointer

Tags: c++

In this code I ask the user for his name, hours worked and rate per hour, then multiply both to get his salary. I am doing this via a pointer function but for some reason when the program goes to the calculate_salary function, it ends with an error. What is wrong and why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
    public:
        string name;
        double salary;
        double hours;
        double cash_per_hour;

        int age;
        Employee(){}
        double* salary_calculator(double *h, double *c_p_h)
        {
            double *p;
            *p = (*h) * (*c_p_h);
            cout << "here" << endl;

            return(p);
        }

        void display()
        {
            cout << endl << endl << "*********************" << endl
                 << "The salary is " << salary << endl
                 << "*********************" << endl;
        }

        void get_salary()
        {
            double *s;

            s = salary_calculator(&hours, &cash_per_hour);

            salary = *s;
        }

        void get_details()
        {
            cout << "********************************" << endl;
            cout << "WELCOME TO THE SALARY CALCULATOR" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter your name " << endl;
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Please enter the number of hours worked" << endl;
            cin >> hours;
            cout << "Please enter the rate per hour" << endl;
            cin >> cash_per_hour;
            cout << "***************END****************" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Employee one;
    one.get_details();
    one.get_salary();
    one.display();

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I hope you would try indent your code.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the program stops working after the get_details function

Comment: Why are you using pointers when you can use references?

Comment: trying to learn more about pointers

Comment: Do you mean a function that returns pointers, or a 'function pointer'?

Comment: The function salry_calculator returns a pointer to a double. However, the variable p goes out of scope. Furthermore, you use unnessary pointers such as in the function get_salary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in my comment: the function returns a pointer to the variable `p`. However `p` goes out of scope (i.e., only exist in the function itself). Therefore the pointer which is returned points to something and we do not know to what, also called a wild pointer.

To avoid this you should just return by value since this is a primitive type. When you really want to return a pointer you have to allocate memory. For an object, you can allocate memory with the function new. For example: `double *p = new double;`.

Keep in mind that you have to free this allocated memory when you don't need it anymore, otherwise you will have a memory leak. Read more about this here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_dynamic_memory.htm

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `p` in `salary_calculator` is not associated with any allocated space. Dereferencing it therefore results in undefined behavior.

Instead of using pointers here, just change the return type to `double` and adjust your program according to that.

Comment: I used the same method for another program and it worked.  It is possible to return a pointer through this method but its only this time that im getting an error

Comment: The pointer value could point to a valid location within your program but odds are it doesn't. In your other program you had luck.

Comment: @madridista "Appearing to work" is a possible symptom of undefined behaviour